# Flutter uses the background color for the body but the onSurface for the text

Tags: flutter, color-scheme

i am new to flutter and i created an app with a `Scaffold` containing an appBar, a body and a drawer.
I created my own ColorScheme with custom colors.

Now in the widget that i use as body for my Scaffold, flutter automatically uses the 'background'-color of my scheme as backgroundCOlor, which is fine. But for the `Text`components inside that widget it uses the onSurface color as text color. Shouldn't it use the onBackground color?

edit: i created a simple example to show my confusion.
Yes i know i can set the color of Text component individually, but i don't see why that should be necessary.
I want to understand why flutter uses the 'onSurface' color on the 'background' color:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: const ColorScheme(
          primary: Colors.black,
          onPrimary: Colors.white,
          secondary: Colors.black,
          onSecondary: Colors.white,
          tertiary: Colors.black,
          onTertiary: Colors.white,
          background: Colors.blue,
          onBackground: Colors.red,
          surface: Colors.green,
          onSurface: Colors.yellow,
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
          error: Colors.transparent,
          onError: Colors.red,//
        ),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}


class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('My Title'),),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center (
          child: Text('Some example text'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

in this example flutter automatically uses the followings colors:
AppBar: backgroundColor: scheme.surface(green), textColor: scheme.onSurface(yellow)
body(Center): backgroundColor:scheme.background(blue), textColor:scheme.onSurface(yellow)

Comment: Flutter's default color is to use the `primary color` as the default text color, and if you want to use background color, you need to specify it explicitly in the `TextStyle` of your Text widgets.

Comment: but it doesn't use the primary color... it uses the onSurface color

Comment: i updated my question with a simple runnable example

Comment: It means what you get here in Flutter is by design. Why would you assume that it should use onBackground?

Comment: because it is a text on a container for which it uses background. What else is onBackground for?

Answer (score 0):

`onSurface` is designed to provide high contrast against surface (background) color.

It make sures that text is readable, even with different background color.

You can change text color based `onBackground`

```
return Center(
 child: Column(
   children: [
     Text(
       'Some Text:',
       style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground),
     ),
   ],
 ),
);
```

Comment: I understand your first sentence. And it makes sense that it uses the color for text on the AppBar where it uses the surface background. But why does it use it on the 'background' color?

Comment: i updated my question with a simple runnable example

Comment: i guess `onSurface` provides contrast and readability for both surface(card,sheets,menu) and background(overall bg color).  Check the material guideline https://m2.material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#color-theme-creation https://m3.material.io/styles/color/roles